# How to have parameterized key for a type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, flowtype

I'm in the process of migrating my react-native project from Flow to TypeScript, and one part that I got stuck on is recreating this type from Flow:

```
declare type ApolloData<T, nodeName: string = 'node'> = {
  [nodeName]: ?T,
  viewer?: ?Viewer,
  placeSearch?: ?PlaceConnection,
  contactIqLookup?: ?ContactIq,
};
```

This allowed me to type my data coming from GraphQL as follows:

```
const data: ApolloData<Space> = fetchData();
const space: Space = data.node;
// OR
const data: ApolloData<Space, 'space'> = fetchData();
const space: Space = data.space;
```

---

I tried to recreate this in TypeScript, this was my first attempt:

```
type ApolloData<T, nodeName extends string = 'node'> = {
  [node: nodeName]: T | null;
  viewer?: Viewer | null;
  placeSearch?: PlaceConnection | null;
  contactIqLookup?: ContactIq | null;
}
```

However, this gives an error: `TS1023: An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.`

After doing some research, I learned about the `Record` type and that seemed to be a good fit, so my second attempt was a bit more successful:

```
type ApolloData<T, nodeName extends string = 'node'> = 
    Record<nodeName, T | null> &
    {
      viewer?: Viewer | null;
      placeSearch?: PlaceConnection | null;
      contactIqLookup?: ContactIq | null;
    }
```

But the issue with this is that the other properties get typed as `viewer: Viewer | null | T` instead of just `Viewer | null` since the `Record` type is for all properties of that object.

Is there any way in typescript to accept a generic parameterized key and value but also have other fields?

Comment: Why do you say `viewer: Viewer | null | T` ? From my testing when you create instances of `ApolloData` it all works out as it should ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?  Simply breakup the `Record` definition versus the other static attributes and combine them afterwards

```
type ContactIq = { _type: "ContactIq" };
type PlaceConnection = { _type: "PlaceConnection" };
type Viewer = { _type: "Viewer" };

type DataOnly<T, nodeName extends string> = Record<nodeName, T | null>;

interface OtherAttributes {
  viewer?: Viewer | null;
  placeSearch?: PlaceConnection | null;
  contactIqLookup?: ContactIq | null;
}

type ApolloData<T, nodeName extends string = 'node'> = OtherAttributes & DataOnly<T, nodeName>;

const data1: ApolloData<string> = {
  node: "test",
  viewer: { _type: "Viewer" },
  contactIqLookup: { _type: "ContactIq" },
  placeSearch: { _type: "PlaceConnection" }
}

const data2: ApolloData<string, "abc"> = {
  abc: "test",
  viewer: { _type: "Viewer" },
  contactIqLookup: { _type: "ContactIq" },
  placeSearch: { _type: "PlaceConnection" }
}
```